# Frequent screen freezes with Ubuntu 18.04.2 even for small tasks (even mouse don't move)

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics, mouse

I installed `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS` OS on a Windows 10 dual boot and till one month it worked fine without any issues. I am a beginner in UBuntu OS ans I setup OS myself following online tutorials.

Recently, I am facing screen freezes multiple times, everytime I need to force stop and wait for sometime and then start again. I tried several online tutorials to fix my issues. My hardware configuration is nvidia Graphics and i7-8th gen with 16GB RAM.

I tried the following command and instead of nvidia, VGA compatibilty shows Intel. Not sure, which one is correct.

Here's the output:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b


lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 086f
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
    Memory behind bridge: a3000000-a40fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000090000000-00000000a1ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 086f
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 142
    Memory at a2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 144
    Memory at a3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at a4000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

I am currently using nvidia-390 driver and lightDM package. Please suggest if this is the problem with Graphics or should I install any software/drivers for these issues?

Comment: You can try updating the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: I resolved the issue by rebooting OS. Actually the issue is with "tasksel" which deleted my core files when I tried uninstalling LAMP stack.